# Change alpha for a particular graph using layers in ggplot and keep the legend the same?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, alpha

Using the following data frame:

```
sdf<-data.frame(hours=gl(n=3,k=1,length=9,labels=c(0,2,4)),    
                count=c(4500,1500,2600,4000,800,200,1500,50,20),
                machine=gl(n=3,k=3,length=9,labels=c("A","B","C")))
```

The following graph can be produced using either of these scripts:

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="A",])+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="B",])+
  geom_area(data=sdf[sdf$machine=="C",])

ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine))+
  geom_area(position="dodge")
```

[image]

The color can easily be changed, but changing the alpha value also changes the legend:

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine,alpha=machine))+
  geom_area(position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chocolate1","goldenrod","pink"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.01, 0.2, .1),guide=F)
```

[image]

Ideally, the legend will not fade to the same alpha values. This might sound strange for an individual graph, but the result will be part of a .gif file.

Question: What script can alter the alpha values for individual graphs yet keep the solidity of colors in the legend?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you used for the final plot? `guide = F` makes the legend stay at `alpha = 1` for me

Comment: Using version=0.97.237, R produces the graph that I pasted above. You might need to try an older command like legend=F or something along those lines.

Comment: n.b.: 0.97.237 is your version of RStudio, not R itself. `sessionInfo()` will give you your version of R & various other useful information.

Comment: R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering rather than commenting here so I can post the image*

That's odd: using R 3.0.0 and `ggplot2` 0.9.3.1, the following code (same as what you posted)

```
ggplot(data=sdf,aes(x=hours,y=count,group=machine,fill=machine,alpha=machine))+
  geom_area(position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chocolate1","goldenrod","pink"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.01, 0.2, .1),guide=F)
```

gives me

[image]

which has `alpha` at 1 in the guide. That makes sense, because `guide=F` has turned off the `scale_alpha_manual` guide, allowing `alpha` to default to 1.

Comment: yep, just what I see - R 3.01 ggplot 0.9.3.1